# Using Keyboard Binds in IF statements

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I am currently developing a tile-based RPG Game where a hero has a strike ability that should only be available when the hero & the skeleton(enemy) are in the same position. I've managed to identify when H and S are in the same position. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
def strike():
    if hero.x == skeleton.xx and hero.y == skeleton.yy and spaceBar(event=):
        skeleton.chp -= hero.sp

def battle():
    if hero.x == skeleton.xx and hero.y == skeleton.yy:
        canvas.create_text(123, 760, text=f"Skeleton (Level {skeleton.mlvl}) HP: {skeleton.chp}/{skeleton.mhp} | DP: {skeleton.mdp} | SP: {skeleton.msp}")
        strike()
    else:
        pass
```

the italic section functions properly and shows the current stats of the skeleton when collision happens.

```
def spaceBar(event):
    for i in range(400):
        canvas.create_image(hero.x * IMG_SIZE, hero.y * IMG_SIZE, image=getattr(root, "strike"), anchor=NW)'
```

**My question is simply, how can I bind the spaceBar event into the strike function because it requires an event within the () as a condition.**

Thank you for having a look I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `event` object in `spaceBar()` is not used at all, you can use default value of argument to make it an optional argument: `def spaceBar(event=None)`.  Then you can call it without argument inside `strike()`.

```py
def spaceBar(event=None):
    for i in range(400):
        canvas.create_image(hero.x * IMG_SIZE, hero.y * IMG_SIZE, image=getattr(root, "strike"), anchor=NW)
```

```py
def strike():
    if hero.x == skeleton.xx and hero.y == skeleton.yy and spaceBar():
        skeleton.chp -= hero.sp
```